# Aspx controls vs HTML tags in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net

let -

`<asp:TextBox id="txt" Runat="Server"></asp:TextBox>`

and html tag

```
<input id="name" runat="server" />
```

The aspx controls e.g Textbox which later gets converted to html tag or renders, but what if I use html tag with runat='server' attribute, In which case the performance is better???

Comment: You're micro optimizing things. Choose pure html if you don't need to access it on serverside and server controls otherwise. I'm always using servercontrols (so f.e. a `Panel` instead of a `div`) since there is no noticable difference but it's easier if i have to access them later.

Answer (score 0):

They are essentially same. However, writing html tags and attributes manually is fragile, and you can only catch errors at run-time.

On the other-hand, you can catch most the server control errors at design time. In addition, server control has **ViewState** which maintains the persistent of data between postbacks.

You need to draw the line between performance and maintainability.